# Magento add field in order error

Tags: magento

I am trying to add new field in order of magento by run this code:

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
/* @var $addressHelper Mage_Customer_Helper_Address */
$addressHelper = Mage::helper('customer/address');
$store         = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

/* @var $eavConfig Mage_Eav_Model_Config */
$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');

// update customer address user defined attributes data
$attributes = array(
    'district_id'           => array(   
        'label'    => 'ID District',
        'type'     => 'varchar',
        'input'    => 'text',
        'is_user_defined'   => 1,
        'is_system'         => 0,
        'is_visible'        => 1,
        'sort_order'        => 140,
        'is_required'       => 1,
        'multiline_count'   => 0,
        'validate_rules'    => array(
            'max_text_length'   => 255,
            'min_text_length'   => 1
        ),
    ),
);

foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $data) {
    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
    $attribute->setWebsite($store->getWebsite());
    $attribute->addData($data);
        $usedInForms = array(
            'adminhtml_customer_address',
            'customer_address_edit',
            'customer_register_address'
        );
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
    $attribute->save();
}

$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_quote_address')} ADD COLUMN `district_id` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fax`;
     ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_order_address')} ADD COLUMN `district_id` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fax`;
    ");
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

But when i am login to admin and click to view customer detail.
It have error:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on boolean
What wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in installer script

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'district_id', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'District Id',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'district_id')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address',
                                     'customer_address_edit',
                                     'adminhtml_customer_address'))
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming that you want to add my_custom_input_field to your order and add a field to your admin create order page (to add the field to the frontend you just need to add the input field to the front template and double check the observer)

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderStatus/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus>
    </modules>

    <global> 
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                           
                <my_custom_input_field><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_input_field>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                              
                <my_custom_input_field><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_input_field>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
            <customorderstatus>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Helper</class>
            </customorderstatus>            
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <customorderstatus>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customorderstatus_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </customorderstatus>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customorderstatus_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customorderstatus_setup>
            <customorderstatus_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customorderstatus_write>
            <customorderstatus_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customorderstatus_read>
        </resources>

        <events>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
                <observers>
                    <customorderstatus>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customorderstatus/observer</class>
                        <method>saveCustomData</method>
                    </customorderstatus>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
        </events>

        <blocks>
            <customorderstatus>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Block</class>
            </customorderstatus>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
In 

    /app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderStatus/sql/customorderstatus_setup/mysql4-install-1.1.php

    <?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field", array("type"=>"varchar"));
    $installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field", array("type"=>"varchar"));
    $installer->endSetup();

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderStatus/Model/Observer.php

    class MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Model_Observer 
    {
        public function saveCustomData($event)
        {
            $quote = $event->getSession()->getQuote();
            $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field', $event->getRequestModel()->getPost('my_custom_input_field'));

            return $this;
        }
    }

(You should avoid make changes to core default - you should do some research on way around this)

In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml

<?php if($_order->getMyCustomInputField()): ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Custom Input Field') ?></label></td>
        <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $_order->getMyCustomInputField() ?></strong></td>
    </tr>

<?php endif; ?>

In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form/account.phtml

(to add to frontend change the value="<?php echo Mage...>")

    <input id="my_custom_input_field" name="my_custom_input_field" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote()->getMyCustomInputField() ?>" class="input-text" type="text">
```